# How to pass props to named views through <router-link /> in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I’m new to VueJS and front end development.
I’m looking to pass a props (in this case, my club’s id) to my component/view.

It was initially working with `<router-link :to="{ name: 'club', params: {id: club.id } }">`.
My component call a props “id”, and my view, named club has the parameter props:true;

Fast forward a little later, i had to add named view. (I only added one for now - but i’ll have a view content and one nav).

```
mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  linkExactActiveClass: 'is-active',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'clubs',
      components: {
        content: Clubs
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/club/:id',
      name: 'club',
      props: true,
      components: {
        content: Club
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

And this broke everything.
In the Vue extension, i can see that my send is sending my props as a param (see attachement 1), but once on the view, the id is undefined (see attachment 2).

Am i missing anything?

Attachement 1
[image: Router Link]

Attachement 2
[image: View Data]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to set a `props` value for each named view in that case. e.g.

```js
components: {
  content: Club
},
props: {
  content: true
}
```

I can't find a decent explanation of this in the documentation but it does feature in an example here:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Note the following comment lurking in the code example:

```js
// for routes with named views, you have to define the `props` option for each named view:
```

Comment: And that worked indeed!
Thank you @skirtle :) - I'm almost sur i ended on this doc page during my research and tried it already, but i probably had something else messed up at this time :)