# Pass props in Vue Router with multiple components

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

I'm trying to pass a prop to a component in the router if on a specific route.

All the tutorial found only use one component so the prop can simple be appended to the list.

But with multiple components it doesnt work.

```
name: "Room",
  components: {
    navbar: TitleRooms,
    content: Room,
    props: {
        title: "message"
      }
  }
```

I tried this, but it simply does nothing.

```
name: "Room",
  components: {
    navbar: {
      TitleRooms,
      props: {
        title: "message"
      }
    },
    content: Room
  }
```

I also tried this one, but it also doesn't work.

Is there an option to do this properly with multiple nested named router-views?

Comment: Could you add a little more context? It's a bit difficult to reverse engineer what you're trying to do when all we have is code that doesn't work. Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807262/how-to-pass-props-to-named-views-through-router-link-in-vuejs/57807580#57807580

Comment: Im trying to pass a value from the router to the navbar: TitleRooms component, when the user hits a specific route.  They are both inside another nested <router-view> and all the Tutoroials I found so far only pass params with the component:{}, but none actually with components:{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you're trying to do this:

```js
name: "Room",
components: {
  navbar: TitleRooms,
  content: Room
},
props: {
  navbar: {
    title: "message"
  },
  content: false
}
```

This should pass the value `"message" for the prop`title`to`TitleRooms`. It won't pass any props to`Room`. If you want to pass props to both components you can just change the`false` to an appropriate object containing the props you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your route renders **Room** component, so this one receives params. Of course Navbar can receive its props, but you should do it via `template`. Do:

```html
<navbar :title="title" />
```

Which binds `this.title` in Room component (from route param) to Navbar